# POSTing a file to SkyDrive using Socket and REST, nothing happens

Tags: c#, sockets, rest, onedrive

My class library needs an interface to SkyDrive.

(Can I just quickly say that I think what Microsoft have provided in the way of online technical documentation for developing on SkyDrive if totally inadequate, IMHO.)

Currently my library can sign in, download files and delete files, using a combination of the Microsoft.Live API and the Socket class.  (I cannot use high level socket classes, such as HttpWebRequest and WebClient, so I am using the Socket class.)

But I am stuck at uploading a file.

Here is a simple request that posts a file to a SkyDrive account:

```
private const string API_SERVICE_URI = "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/";
private const string REST_DATA_BOUNDARY = "A300x";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("POST {0}me/skydrive/files?access_token={1}\r\n",
    API_SERVICE_URI,
    _liveSession.AccessToken
);
sb.Append("\r\n");
sb.AppendFormat("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary={0}\r\n", 
    REST_DATA_BOUNDARY
);
sb.Append("\r\n");
sb.AppendFormat("--{0}\r\n", REST_DATA_BOUNDARY);
sb.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"test.txt\"\r\n");
sb.AppendFormat("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n");
sb.Append("\r\n");
sb.Append("abcdefg\r\n");
sb.AppendFormat("--{0}--\r\n", REST_DATA_BOUNDARY);
```

When I send this via a connected socket, nothing happens.  No reply.  No error.  Nothing.

Am I right sending this down the Socket as is?  I'm just serializing the whole thing as ASCII and sending it.  Am I meant to include some authentication or cookie values because it’s going over SSL?  Is that why nothing is coming back?

Comment: Why can't you use an Http library ?

Comment: Why can't you use `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest` ?

Comment: Classes like HttpWebRequest will run in a worker thread, but dispatch calls to the UI for every read.  I want a SkyDrive library that runs in the background and stays there.

Comment: @BrainProxy `Classes like HttpWebRequest will run in a worker thread, but dispatch calls to the UI for every read` Not true unless you use their async methods.

Comment: On WP7 and Silverlight there is only async.